# How should I use Ansible to add a repository to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am getting started with Ansible. My Ansible host and remote target are both Ubuntu 16.04. I tried using ansible nginx playbook but I am getting too many errors.

Here is my playbook:

```
- hosts: testbed
  tasks:

      - name: Install the Nginx Repository
        apt_repository:
          repo: ppa:nginx/stable
          state: present
        become: yes
        become_method: sudo
```

This is my hosts file:

```
[testbed]
myserveripaddr.compute-1.amazonaws.com

[testbed:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
ansible_become_pass=mydeployer_pswd
ansible_become_user=mydeployer
```

I am executing ansible with the following command line:

```
ansible-playbook base.yml -vvv
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
<myserveripaddr.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<myserveripaddr.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/manish/.ansible/cp/ec8ae2c055 myserveripaddr.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1531936359.43-119337047930812/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<myserveripaddr.compute-1.amazonaws.com> (0, '', '')
fatal: [myserveripaddr.compute-1.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": "apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 8B3981E7A6852F782CC4951600A6F0A3C300EE8C", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "codename": null, 
            "filename": null, 
            "install_python_apt": true, 
            "mode": null, 
            "repo": "ppa:nginx/stable", 
            "state": "present", 
            "update_cache": true, 
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "gpg: requesting key C300EE8C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com\ngpg: key C300EE8C: public key \"Launchpad Stable\" imported\ngpg: Total number processed: 1\ngpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)\ngpg: no writable keyring found: eof\ngpg: error reading `[stdin]': general error\ngpg: import from `[stdin]' failed: general error\ngpg: Total number processed: 0", 
    "rc": 1, 
    "stderr": "gpg: requesting key C300EE8C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com\ngpg: key C300EE8C: public key \"Launchpad Stable\" imported\ngpg: Total number processed: 1\ngpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)\ngpg: no writable keyring found: eof\ngpg: error reading `[stdin]': general error\ngpg: import from `[stdin]' failed: general error\ngpg: Total number processed: 0\n", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "gpg: requesting key C300EE8C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com", 
        "gpg: key C300EE8C: public key \"Launchpad Stable\" imported", 
        "gpg: Total number processed: 1", 
        "gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)", 
        "gpg: no writable keyring found: eof", 
        "gpg: error reading `[stdin]': general error", 
        "gpg: import from `[stdin]' failed: general error", 
        "gpg: Total number processed: 0"
    ], 
    "stdout": "Executing: /tmp/tmp.vjwZQC7PG8/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys\n--keyserver\nhkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80\n8B3981E7A6852F782CC4951600A6F0A3C300EE8C\n", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Executing: /tmp/tmp.vjwZQC7PG8/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys", 
        "--keyserver", 
        "hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80", 
        "8B3981E7A6852F782CC4951600A6F0A3C300EE8C"
    ]
}
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ansible_become_user` is the user "you become" so you are trying to execute the task as the `mydeployer` user. You cannot do that, you should run it as the `root`.

Remove `ansible_become_user=mydeployer` from your inventory. Or change it to `ansible_become_user=root`, but this is default value anyway.